# Emacs, insert rectangular string interactively

Tags: emacs, elisp

I often encounter situations in editing text or code where I want to insert a rectangle of spaces to align things, but I don't know exactly the number of spaces to insert.

For example, consider the following (very much contrived) snippet:

```
void *var = (void *)typedVar;
void *otherVar = voidStarOtherVar;
int intVar = x*y;
int intVar2 = y*z;
```

In default C-mode, `M-x align` results in this, which is better:

```
void *var      = (void *)typedVar;
void *otherVar = voidStarOtherVar;
int   intVar   = x*y;
int   intVar2  = y*z;
```

However, suppose my desired alignment (for some reason) is this:

```
void *var      = (void *)typedVar;
void *otherVar =         voidStarOtherVar;
int   intVar   =         x*y;
int   intVar2  =         y*z;
```

The only way I know to do that is with `M-x string-rectangle` on the bottom three lines, and type in the exact number of spaces.

However, I don't want to count the number of characters in `(void *)` before typing in the spaces, thus it would be nice to have an "interactive" rectangle string insert. For example, I type a space in this interactive mode, and I see it reflected immediately in the text. I enter another space, and it is inserted. In this way I can interactively align the text to my desired position.

Is there a built-in way to accomplish this? Or, failing that, can I create this functionality somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open rectangle may be useful for your example:

> `C-x r o' Insert blank space to fill the space of the region-rectangle
>   (`open-rectangle').  This pushes the previous contents of the
>   region-rectangle to the right.

So you mark the desired rectangle, and this function will push content to the right of the rectangle.

Comment: This is great! Thanks. One followup question: is there such a thing as a rectangular mark? For example, if I want to select a rectangle but there isn't enough text to move to the right to the desired column. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @proc-self-maps Any of the two solutions I presented does what you call "rectangular mark", I'm not sure if `multiple-cursors` will do it as well.  They also each have immediate feedback of space insertion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The built-in mode is `cua-selection-mode`.

Here is a [video](http://vimeo.com/1168225?pg=embed&sec=1168225) of `cua-mode` working.  `cua-selection-mode` activates just the rectangular selection aspect of it.

You can also get this functionality with `iedit`, but that's an [external package](https://github.com/victorhge/iedit).  Its main purpose is editing mirrors.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to those already presented is `multiple-cursors` on [github](https://github.com/emacsmirror/multiple-cursors), which is highly interactive and quite fun. There's a sublime [Emacs Rocks!](http://emacsrocks.com/e13.html) episode covering it on YouTube.